# Need to insert price table into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a table and i need to ad new records a row in the mysql database. Now i do this manually for each record but there are 600 records in each table.

I have this columns in the row where it must be instert called "curtain_entry_item" database:

group  > This is the record that connects the price table for example this is price table 31.

width > this could be 20 cm 30 cm etc. till 240

length > this could be 20 cm 30 cm etc. till 300

price> this could be 30

So how can i execute this table in one action in to the mysql database.

You can see an example of the table at[this link](http://www.netidentity.nl/prijslijst.xlsx)

Much thanks! Wouter

Comment: 'I have a table' ... so show this table. And say once more, how many TABLES You have? Maybe I dont understand, but porting Excell philosophy to relational database seems wrong

Comment: As you have the data in excel, if this is a one-off, and given you only have a few columns, you could consider building a SQL INSERT statement for each row by building and replicating an excel function, then copying the resulting sql from there into mysql workbench and running it. Here's an example such function that I use regularly: =CONCATENATE("insert into mytable (mycol1,mycol2) values(",C2,",'",D2,"');")

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

As there is no exact details of your database structure is not possible to give you working solution.

My guess is that you need INSERT INTO SELECT statement which copies data from one table and inserts it into another table. You can find more details from w3scools at:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to transform your spreadsheet matrix into a set of SQL commands that load a database table.

If so, this is more of an input-parsing question than a database question.

The general approach would be to:

```
for each row
    for each column
        issue an INSERT statement using the row, column and intersection cell
```

Here is a Perl program that will do that with, e.g., the first tab of the spreadsheet you provided (after exporting it to CSV):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# read in the header line and trim off whitespce
$header = <STDIN>;
$header =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

# make the header line into an array of 'width' values
@widths = split(/,/, $header);

# loop through the remaining (data) rows
while ($data = <STDIN>) {
    # trim whitespace
    $data =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

    # split the row into data elements, and use the 1st one as the 'length'
    @prices = split(/,/, $data);
    $length = $prices[0];

    # loop through the remaining data cells
    for ($i = 1; $i < 23; $i++) {
        # print out an appropriate INSERT statement
        printf(STDOUT "INSERT INTO curtain_price_table (group, width, length, price) VALUES (31, %d, %d, %d);\n", $widths[$i], $length, $prices[$i] . "\n");
    }
}
```

Perl is NOT your only option here; any scripting language can do this same task pretty easily.  And, you might need to adapt this to make it a general-purpose solution for your various input files and database tables.  But this should provide enough information for you to solve your need.

Comment: I'm tempted to up-vote your answer, but I'm torn because even though your answer is useful its larger effect is to reward people who ask questions that are too vague and lack clarity and ultimately put the onus on the community to try and figure out what exactly the OP is asking - which I think should be discouraged. So I'm not upvoting - but I am down voting the question.

Comment: @GeniaS. I genuinely appreciate what you are saying, but I'd ask you to reconsider;  I'm still very low on reputation, and most questions are answered very quickly;  I'm willing to put in the extra effort to decipher a less-clear question that most people pass up, in order to build up reputation; also, I was a noob once (well before SO), and found it quite helpful when colleagues would have patience with my incompletely-worded questions;  so, please reconsider -- your up-vote would help me help others;  thanks!